# How to build a message object with map<String, Object> of data type in client?

Tags: dictionary, protocol-buffers, grpc-java

I want to create a rpc which is having a Request parameter message with 
map data type.

This is my proto file.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package vat;

service VatRecognizer {

    rpc recognizeRequest(Request) returns (Response) {}
}

message Request {
    string method = 1;
    map <string, ApiParams> inputParams = 2;
}

message ApiParams {
    repeated ParamsList params = 1;
}

message ParamsList {
    string key = 1;
    string value = 2;
}

message Response {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 1;
    map <string, string> result = 2;
}

ParamsList paramsList = ParamsList.newBuilder().setKey("key").setValue("xyz").build();
        ApiParams apiParams = ApiParams.newBuilder().addParams(paramsList).build();
Request request = Request.newBuilder().setField(FileDescriptor, object value). build();
```

How I can set Request.newBuilder().setField(FileDescriptor, object value)? It's not taking map here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For protobuf map type, protobuf generated code provides two methods; one for a key value pair, the other for java map of key value pairs.

```java
Request.newBuilder()
  // Adding one key value pair
  .putResult("key", "value")
  // Adding multiple key value pairs
  .putAllResult(ImmutableMap.of("keyA", "valueA", "keyB", "valyeB"))
  .build();
```

Comment: Thanks creamsoup, I recompiled the proto and now getting put method.